# Different implementation of HoughLinesP on GPU and CPU

Tags: c++, opencv

I am supposed to port an app to GPU. The app makes extensive use of OpenCV (opencv4tegra). I noticed that HoughLinesP doesn't have the same prototype on CPU and GPU. For example the CPU prototype is this:

```
CV_EXPORTS_W void HoughLinesP( InputArray image, OutputArray lines,
                       double rho, double theta, int threshold,
                       double minLineLength=0, double maxLineGap=0 );
```

The GPU implementation has this prototype:

```
CV_EXPORTS void HoughLinesP(const GpuMat& image, GpuMat& lines, HoughLinesBuf& buf, float rho, float theta, int minLineLength, int maxLineGap, int maxLines = 4096);
```

The threshold parameter is missing from GPU implementation and because of this I get different results for the same image. 
Is there an explanation why CPU and GPU functions are not the same? Also why is there no support for streams for HoughLinesP on GPU ?

Comment: not sure about the threshold param, but if your app will run on a tegra platform then GPU will probably be slower than the CPU version (typically the cpu functions use tegra support if available)

Comment: I'm not referring to difference in speed but difference in resulted lines. For example by using the same values for the parameters, the GPU version detects more lines on the same picture for which the CPU version detected a small number of lines. By the way, HoughLinesP is faster on GPU on large images using CudaMem.
Also why is there no support for streams for the GPU version ?

Comment: are you using OpenCV4Tegra? I did understand that you were referring to differences in the results, but I can't help you about that. So the idea was to use OpenCV4Tegra with CPU version (which should give you the results you want because of the threshold param in the CPU version) because it might be even faster than the gpu version used by OpenCV-GPU module. But if the speed of the GPU version is better for you then this idea doesn't help ;)

Comment: Thanks Micka, but do you have any idea why the implementation is different, why is the GPU version missing this parameter ?

Comment: unfortunately not. `HoughLinesP` isn't even mentioned in http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/image_processing.html for the GPU module. Only `HoughLines`